# Proper way to do proxy in apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I am having issues in setting a reverse proxy in my apache server.
I have the location /porteiner

```
<Location "/porteiner">
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</Location>
```

That should proxy evertything that it receives in myserver.com/porteiner to the service runnin in the 9000 port but apache isnt proxying the path right and i am getting the errors:

```
192.168.0.2 - - [22/Mar/2018:12:01:30 -0300] "GET /css/app.e3710651.css HTTP/1.1" 404 218 ".nhttp://myserver.com/porteiner" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
192.168.0.2 - - [22/Mar/2018:12:01:30 -0300] "GET /js/app.eb337e10.js HTTP/1.1" 404 216 "http://myserver.com/porteiner" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
192.168.0.2 - - [22/Mar/2018:12:01:30 -0300] "GET /images/logo_alt.png HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "http://myserver.com/porteiner" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
```

Why it is not translating the / to /porteiner as asked in the config?

Comment: Maybe you want it the opposite way, `<Location "/">` and `http://127.0.0.1:9000/portainer/`?

Comment: There are other stuff in the server root.